# Imagemagick and .pes format

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert an image file to .pes format (and embroidery format) using imagemagick.

```
convert example.jpg test.pes
```

which returns

```
convert: no encode delegate for this image format `PES'
```

I have installed Imagemagick from source, my delegates are listed as

```
DELEGATES      mpeg fontconfig freetype png ps x xml zlib
```

How would i find a delegate for the .pes filetype?

[this exists](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/coders/pes.c), but i don't know what i'm supposed to do with it

this is the [delegates page](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/delegates/) will any of these help me?

Comment: The linked PES coder file allows ImageMagick to _read_ PES format, but not write PES files. You can verify by running `identify -list Format | grep PES`

Comment: thanks for that. the PES coder does state 'Read/Write Brother PES Image Format'. still not sure how to convert to PES

Comment: The imagemagick format page at https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php list Read only for PES format. `  PES* PES       r--   Embrid Embroidery Format`. r-- means read only (no write and no execute)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

PES files are embroidery files. Embroidery files are much more like vectors than they are like graphics files. They by definition contain a list of overt commands that expressly tell an embroidery file what it must do to sew an embroidery. As such, they contain position/movement commands for the machine. This is not something that can be made directly from a raster image anymore than you can send a raster into svg format.